# position:absolute is not working in IE 8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I have a code to play a track, where you can see the track with the seek bar and play bar with an opacity. This code work is mozilla but not in IE 8. IE 8 does not respond. If i remove absolute the code will work but with distortion position.
with HTML code

```
<div class="jp-progress wav">
    <img class="waveform" alt="" src="http://static.supajam.com/a/8d/5058-1298536709311_waveform-bg.png">
   <div class="jp-seek-bar" >
    <div class="jp-play-bar" ></div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

the css for following code is

```
div.jp-audio div.jp-progress {
    position: absolute;
    top:32px;
    height:69px;
}

div.jp-seek-bar {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: '1000';
     top: 0;
    width:0px;
    height:81px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

div.jp-play-bar {
    width:0px;
    height:51px;
     border-right: 2px solid #ef6920;
    background-color: #ef6920;
    opacity: 0.3;
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
}
```

If any can help, I would be grateful to them.

Comment: Explain your problem with help of this http://jsfiddle.net/RLEeu/ . What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Could try,

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Not ideal but, supporting older browsers really drains time.